# Shuffle two lists in the same way

Tags: c#, ienumerable, shuffle

I want to shuffle two lists, such that they are shuffled in the same way (provided that I have a method Shuffle(List list) that shuffles one list.

```
List<ObjX> listA = new List<ObjX>() { A, B, C, D };
List<ObjX> listB = new List<ObjX>() { W, X, Y, Z };
ShuffleTwoLists(listA , listB )
```

Result:
A: C, B, D, A
B: Y, X, Z, W

Is there a quick way to implement ShuffleTwoLists(listA , listB) in C#?

Comment: zip, shuffle, unzip

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Option 1: zip, shuffle, unzip**

To expand on Marcelo's comment, and assuming you don't mind creating *new* lists instead of shuffling the *existing* ones:

```
var zipped = listA.Zip(listB, (a, b) => new { a, b } ).ToList();
Shuffle(zipped);
var newListA = zipped.Select(pair => pair.a).ToList();
var newListB = zipped.Select(pair => pair.b).ToList();
```

**Option 2: shuffle the indexes**

To expand on MAK's answer with code:

```
var indexes = Enumerable.Range(0, listA.Count).ToList();
Shuffle(indexes);
var newListA = indexes.Select(index => listA[index]).ToList();
var newListB = indexes.Select(index => listB[index]).ToList();
```

Of course both approaches *could* mutate the original lists, with a bit more work.

**Option 3: shuffle both lists with the same random seed**

I personally like to pass a `Random` (or whatever) into methods/classes which need them instead of creating new ones. So I'd give my `Shuffle` a `Random` parameter. It avoids various problems, and expresses the dependency nicely. You can use this to your advantage, by creating two `Random` instances with the same seed:

```
int seed = existingRandom.Next();
Shuffle(listA, new Random(seed));
Shuffle(listB, new Random(seed));
```

Assuming `Shuffle` does the same thing when given the same sequence of random numbers, this will shuffle both lists in the same way.

Comment: @MarceloCantos: While I was hoping you wouldn't mind me using your idea :)

Comment: +1. I wanted to circle back and post code after a few minutes, but work got in the way. Thanks.

Comment: I don't really like Option 3. One weakness is that you'll only get 2 billion different permutations. And IMO it's the one that's the most anti-DI, since it creates its own instances of `Random`, which doesn't allow one to inject a different implementation of `Random`, for example because you better performance or quality. | But I'll admit those are just reasons I found afterwards to justify my dislike. I'd dislike it even without those reasons, since it feels unintuitive to me.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: You could mitigate both of those by also passing in a `Func<long, IRandom>` or something similar (for some suitable `IRandom` interface), which would give a random using the relevant seed. (You'd need to do a bit of work to use 64 bits for the seed for `Random` itself, perhaps creating two `Random` instances and combining rseults, or something like that.)

Answer (score 5):

All of Jon's techniques are good. An additional technique is:

```
class PermutedList<T> 
{
    private readonly IList<T> underlying;
    private readonly IList<int> permutation;
    public T this[int i]
    {
        get { return underlying[permutation[i]]; }
    }
    ...
```

That is, make a wrapper class around the underlying list. Make a permutation by shuffling an array with the numbers 0 through n-1. If you apply the same permutation array to two different lists, then you'll get the same "shuffle" of the two different lists. Make sense?

Comment: And for added craziness, add the setter too, and confuse the heck out of everyone :) (I'm personally quite fond of my third solution now that I've thought of it... for the emphasis on dependency injection of `Random` if nothing else)

Comment: +1 - I like this method in the case presented in the question (with just `int` values) because it acts similar to a collection of pointers in C++, though I wonder if there would be any benefit if `permutation` wasn't a collection of `int`s.

Answer (score 2):

Take a new List of ints, whose contents are all the numbers in `[0, length of A and B)`. These correspond to indices of the elements in your lists. Shuffle that list. Now permute both of your original lists using the shuffled indices.

Comment: I am looking for a generic solution. I will update the sample.

Comment: @Gjorgji: This *is* a generic solution. The `int` values here aren't the values in the original lists - they're the *indexes*. The original lists could be strings, Guids, whatever.